# How to correctly calculate dBv using voltage sample points?

Tags: signal, microphone

I'm working on a noise detection application and now I can read the `Vout` value of the MEMS microphone VM1010.

By searching on the Internet, I find `dBv = 20 * log10(V / 1)` to calculate the dBv value. However, using this formula with my sampled average 0.8V voltage, I get a `-2 dBv` value. But the normal range of dBV stated in the datasheet of the microphone is about -17 to -98 dBV for 35dB SPL to 115 dB SPL. Where possiblely am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You're measuring the output DC offset, which is 0.8V regardless of any signal. With an oscilloscope, you would need to measure the RMS voltage amplitude of the analog output signal to get the correct voltage.

With your oscilloscope, use AC coupling, and then measure the RMS amplitude. If you can't get a suitable RMS reading, it may be easier to measure peak to peak. For a sine wave, the RMS voltage is 0.707 times the peak-peak voltage.

Comment: P-P or RMS voltage?

Comment: Sounds solid. I will give it a try.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You're right, it's probably RMS... SPL is RMS pressure.

Comment: By using p-p voltage of latest 20ms sample points, I can get  more reaonable db SPL values at 50Hz. But there is still about 30 dbSPL gap comparing to dbSPL values detected by products from markets . Can I just add it to the calculated dbSPL value as an offset since it's a log value?

Comment: @lincr A 30dB difference suggests a pretty significant discrepancy, which leads me to suspect some sort of measurement error. A couple questions - how are you measuring voltage amplitude? At 50Hz, A-weighting (dBA) is -30dB below SPL, are you sure you aren't using weighting?

Comment: My raw sample frequency is 20kHz, and I take a batch of sample points as an measurement interval every 20ms(50Hz is my measurement frequency) , which is 400 points. And take the max value and min value of the total 400 points to calculate p-p volatage. And the chip datasheet has no dBA contents, only with db SPL.

Comment: Thank you @W5VO! I was able to make electrical adjustments to audio equipment using your answer. The manual referred to levels to be measured in dBV, and using your settings in my oscilloscope yielded matching values. =)